# communication between board and the GPS module

Tags: gps, stm32, uart

I'm currently having trouble with talking between the dev board (STM32L476RG) and the GPS module (GP-207U). What my code does now is that, it can print out the very first packet received from GPS to PuTTY and will keep printing the same packet, even if I unplug the Tx wire from the dev board, PuTTY will still keep printing. I suspect that either the buffer that stores the received value is not getting updated(fulshed) or the HAL_UART_Receive() function only run once. (The receive function is in While(1) in main, so I'm confused)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzHJH.png)
(I unpluged the GPS, Putty still prints, so the receive function isn't doing anything after it received the very first packet from GPS)

```
/*retrive data from GPS*/
char UARTRxBuffer[1024] = "";
char RxBuffer[1024] = "";

void GetGPS(void) {
    HAL_UART_Receive(&huart3, (uint8_t *)UARTRxBuffer, 1024, 1000);
    HAL_Delay(100);
    sprintf(RxBuffer,"%s\r\n\r\n", UARTRxBuffer);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)RxBuffer, strlen(RxBuffer), 5000);
    HAL_Delay(100);
}
```

GetGPS() is put into while(1) in main().

I tried everything based on my guesses, but none worked.

Thanks ahead for any sort of help!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the call to `HAL_UART_Receive` is timing out (1000 ms in your code) during the second/subsequent attempts to read the GPS. if so, the buffer contents wouldn't get cleared or overwritten resulting the same data being printed over and over. It might help to read the GPS datasheet/manual to find out the maximum polling speed (here it appears to be ~200ms, considering the 2x 100 ms delays) and adjust the delay if the GPS device cannot keep up.

try this to confirm

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_UART_Receive(/*same as above*/);

if(status == HAL_OK){
  // got valid data
  sprintf(RxBuffer,"%s\r\n\r\n", UARTRxBuffer);
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)RxBuffer, strlen(RxBuffer), 5000);
}
else{
  sprintf(RxBuffer,"read timeout.\r\n\r\n");
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)RxBuffer, strlen(RxBuffer), 5000);
}
```

API reference docs [here](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/63/a8/8f/e3/ca/a1/4c/84/DM00173145.pdf/files/DM00173145.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00173145.pdf) page 1037/2232

Comment: Thanks Shreyas, I tried your code, the terminal is now keep printing read timeout.